# Custom worksheet names when exporting custom Dynamics AX 2012 report to Excel

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, export-to-excel, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I've developed a report using the AX 2012 reporting framework (Controller, DP, Contract classes and a reporting project in VS2010). I have a page break in the report design which correctly splits the data into multiple worksheets when the report is exported to Excel.

However, I can't find a way of naming the worksheets themselves. There's no PageName property in VS2010 that I can see (this is how I'd do it if developing a 'pure' SSRS report without AX being involved).

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get named excel sheets while exporting from SSRS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736918/how-to-get-named-excel-sheets-while-exporting-from-ssrs)

Comment: As mentioned in the 'this is how I'd do it if' section of the question, I'm aware that it's possible using the technique mentioned in the possible duplicate link for standard SSRS reports. However, this doesn't work for an AX report.