# SSRS Page Breaks with Named Tabs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have a report that is broken into three pages. When the report is exported as an Excel file I need the tabs to be named correctly.

My report is in this format:

> **First Page:**
>
> - Table
> - Chart - I have the Chart Properties set to *Add a page break after*.
>
> **Second Page:**
>
> - Matrix - I have the Tablix Properties set to *Add a page break after*.
>
> **Third Page:**
>
> - Chart
> - Chart

I am currently using [this version of Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Udmc.png) to create the report if that matters.

[I have found some useful links about adding page breaks on row groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736918/how-to-get-named-excel-sheets-while-exporting-from-ssrs), but I don't see anything about breaking on the entire matrix or a chart.

Comment: Can you set the pagename property for the entire tablix?

Comment: In other words... go to the tablix properties of Page1>Table and give it a pagename.  Do the same for Page2>Matrix and Page3>First Chart

Comment: @Bostaevski: I don't see the PageName option. https://i.imgur.com/aRoyNMJ.png

Comment: Oh... you know I think they added that feature in 2008 R2.  I'm not sure it's possible prior to that verison.