# How to generate rdl report on multiple files by value

Tags: sql, visual-studio, reporting-services, rdl

I have build a report on Visual Studio 2017 that is a simple table wit multiple columns, all the pages are groupped by specific value (the value on first column) and I've setted the pagebreak option to start a new page on the new value on the group. It's almost perfect, but I've a final question, is it possible to export the report on multiple files with different name (the value name of the group)?

Comment: Yes. You have to create a new .rdl (similar) and rename it

Comment: Try the suggestion here:
[SSRS Page Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736918/how-to-get-named-excel-sheets-while-exporting-from-ssrs)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

In the end I've opted to export to Excel with "pagename" setted for each sheet. With a vba macro I'm able to print later on PDF with the name file equal to sheet name.