# SSRS Grouping Rectangle by Excel Tab

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I may have an interesting conundrum and would appreciate your guidance.

So as you can see in my report image, I am creating a report that has multiple tabs (See 1). Each tab in area denoted by 1, is linked to a grouping rectangle denoted by 2 and 3.

Each rectangle may have 1 to 5 datasets and when we click the corresponding button up top, it navigates to the respect page by the rectangle definition, essentially I did this:

For Rectange,
Visibility expression: iff(parameter!.Tab=X, False, True) **Replace X with the Tab name up there)
For button, I assigned the tab value as the corresponding number.

When viewing the report in the standard view on a webpage, everything works as expected. By when I export the same report to excel, I get one tab, with all the data in one page.

So I attempted to follow the design instructions as described here:
[How to get named excel sheets while exporting from SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736918/how-to-get-named-excel-sheets-while-exporting-from-ssrs/6357608)

and here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MAKslN6Ezuo&ab_channel=MandarGogate

but I don't get the same results. I get one page with all the results at the same time.

What I asking for help with is the following:

When exporting the report to excel, can we:

1. Assign a rectangle to its own excel tab
2. Name the respective excel tab

I would sincerely appreciate your help with this.

[image: Report Design]

Comment: Did you add a page break to the end of each rectangle?

Comment: Yes sir I did. Still did not work

Comment: Which version of SSRS are you using? I think this property was only introduced in 2008R2 but you have SSRS 2008 tagged.