# Excel like multi tab report in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

Is there anyway possible to have a SSRS Report that has excel like tab? Bascially a user has  many data saved in Excel sheet with many tabs (close to 7-8) with little difference in those tabs. Hence he was looking for to built the report that when exported to excel can bring data in those tabs.

Second Question: When I export the report to excel, is it possible to have predefined filters in excel?

Let me know for any questions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the report (2008R2 and up) to break the data up into named tabs when exporting to Excel...
[Reporting Services export to Excel with Multiple Worksheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462902/reporting-services-export-to-excel-with-multiple-worksheets)

I don't think you can have predefined filters in excel (I'm assuming you mean the Excel Auto-Filter stuff on the data ribbon tab) with the basic export to excel functionality in SSRS.  If you go custom (via the ReportViewer control) then you could add logic to update the export file (after exporting) to programmatically add in the filtering options.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i have worked on SSRS, i dont think so we can import parameters in excel same as in report.
However we can show data in separate sheets in excel
As you said data can be in 7-8 sheets, there are properties named 'PageName' and 'Pagebreak' of a tablix. Write the name of the page and add page break between those tablixes.
This will create sheets and also give names on those sheets.