# Export Multiple Datasets to Multiple Excel sheets in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have Three different dataset in one Report, Each Dataset result is binded to a different Table component

When I export as Excel ,I am getting all this in One Excel sheet

I need this in separate excel, How can I do this in SSRS

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reporting Services export to Excel with Multiple Worksheets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462902/reporting-services-export-to-excel-with-multiple-worksheets)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In this Case you have to set PageBreak BreakLocation to END and give unique PageName

Follow these steps

1. Select Table 1 press F4 to open Properties window
2. Find PageBreak Option Set BreakLocation to END,
3. Disabled = False
4. ResetPageNumber False
5. nd finally PageName "Sheet 1"

Follow same steps for other two tables but make sure you have unique PageName like "Sheet 2" and "Sheet 3" in this case...

All the Best!

Comment: This works really well, thanks.  I did notice that if one of the tables is empty, that it doesn't break.  Any way to page break and put in headers even if the resultset is nothing?

Comment: Found a solution - put all of the tables into rectangles, and break on the rectangles -end.  Remember to remove the page breaks on the tables if you had them prior or you'll have double the tabs :)