# Export to Excel with multiple worksheets for multiple datasets

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm building a report in SSRS with TWO separate Datasets.

1. One Dataset EXCLUDES some data for a certain date range.
2. The Second dataset is only for EXCLUDED data for that date range.

I would like to show the EXCLUDED data on a separate worksheet when exported to Excel.

Both datasets have the same fields and need to take the same date range that will be specified in the code and parameters.

I looked up a few suggestions in previous questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462902/reporting-services-export-to-excel-with-multiple-worksheets), but that wouldwork for the SAME single dataset. I don't think it would work for two separate datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two separate datasets, so I'm assuming you have two separate tables.

Right-click on the second table, and click "page break" (I'm not sure if it is within "properties" or not, I no longer use SSRS so I can't check).

When you export it, the second table will show up on the a separate tab/worksheet within the file.

Comment: Thank you. This helped. I later found detailed step by step solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24278895/export-multiple-datasets-to-multiple-excel-sheets-in-ssrs