# Most efficient way to export WHERE clause to excel for multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

so lets say I have this query for example

```
SELECT    *
FROM dbo.test
WHERE (person_ID IN ('person1', 'person2', 'person3', 'person4', 
       'person5', 'person6', 'person7', 'person8', 'person9', 
       'person10', 'person11', 'person12', 'person13', 
       'person14', 'person15', 'person16', 'person17', 
       'person18', 'person19', 'person20'))
```

It gives me all the results for these values in the test table right. I need to save the results for each person into its own excel file or into it's own tab within excel. Instead of writing a query with them all together.

Basically how would I write this query properly so it would give me separate outputs for each person that I could quickly copy and paste into its own excel sheet?

The difficult part for me is I have lets say close to 200+ values in an excel sheet right now that I will be searching against (for example with the above query person1 to 200) It's all in a column so I just formatted all the values with '@', so it would come out as example 'person1', that I just copy and pasted into a whereIN( Clause. If I want to do it separately whats the best way to do it so it will give me a lot of different results back all split up I could copy and paste best with the select all as each person_id could come back with a lot of results.

Also is copy and pasting the easiest way in the end ? For them to go into their own excel file or is there an easier way?

Comment: You will need a scripting language like PHP, Python, or VBA not just the db server (unless you use its console and not a script) where you first connect to your SQL Server, store the particular persons in an array, then pass each item in array into indivdual select queries, finally export each query result in csv (or xlsx if language has an Excel library).

Answer (score 0):

For something like this I would suggest SSRS.  Here is an example that shows how to use [Reporting Services to export an Excel file with Multiple Worksheets in SQL Server 2008 R2 using SSRS Report Designer in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21142541).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample that you can try. It's not the easiest way for everyone, but it is a way that I felt was relatively easy.

I have used MS Access 2013 in this sample of convenience instead of SQL Server 2014 or other real, modern RDBMS. You should be able to take this example and adapt for your needs

I created an MS Access file c:\test\Database1.accdb. It contains one table called Table1 with following fields:

- ID
- Firstname
- Lastname
- Age

Data looks like this:

```
ID  Firstname  Lastname  Age
--- ---------- --------- ----
1   John       Smith     12
2   Matt       Johnson   21
```

Then, I created an Excel sheet and saved it as Macro enabled Excel file (Database1.xlsm).

Here're the sequence of events thereafter:

- Name first sheet 1
- If there are any other sheets, delete them
- Go to Data > From Other Sources > From Microsoft Query > MS Access Database > Navigate to c:\test and choose Database1.accdb
- Choose Table 1 and use the > arrow sign to add all fields > Next. Next again. Next again
- Select View data or edit query in Microsoft Query. Click Finish
- Click SQL button
- Ensure that the SQL looks like this (edit the SQL if necessary)

  SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.Firstname, Table1.Lastname, Table1.Age
  FROM `C:\test\Database1.accdb`.Table1 Table1
  where ID = ?
- Click OK. You will be prompted with a dialog box titled Enter Parameter Value. Type 1 and click OK
- X out of (i.e. close out) Microsoft Query
- Import data dialog box will appear with Existing worksheet radio button already selected and `=$A$1` entered. Change that to `=$A$3`
- Right click column A3 > Table > Parameters
- In the Parameters dialog box, select radio button Get the value from the following cell and type in that text box `=A1`
- Go to File > Options > Customize Ribbon > check Developer check box on the right side and click OK ([See instructions if needed](http://www.homeandlearn.org/add-the-developer-toolbar-to-excel.html))
- Go to Developer > Visual Basic
- On top right, click on VBAProject (Database1.xlsm)
- From the application menu on the top, click Insert > Module. Module folder will be created with Module1 in it
- Write the following Sub in it

  Sub Macro1()

  ```
  Dim StartNumber As Integer
  Dim EndNumber As Integer
  StartNumber = 2
  EndNumber = 10

  ' remove all sheets except the first sheet,
  ' assuming first sheet is called 1
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
      If Not ws.Name = "1" Then
          Sheets("1").Select
          ws.Delete
      End If
  Next
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True

  ' make a copy of sheet1 that we prepared carefully
  Dim i As Integer
  For i = StartNumber To EndNumber
      Sheets("1").Select
      Sheets("1").Copy After:=Sheets(i - 1)
      Sheets(i).Select
      Sheets(i).Name = i
  Next

  ' update cell A1 of each sheet
  For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
      ws.Cells(1, 1) = ws.Name
  Next

  ' refresh query in all sheets
  ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
  ```

  End Sub
- Save the file. Close Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications window
- Go to Developer toolbar > Macro > Click Macro1 > Options > Type Shift + t (capital T) in the text box to invoke Macro1 with CTRL+SHIFT+t combination
- Press that combination

You should now see 10 sheets named 1 through 10. Each sheet's cell A1 will contain the name of the sheet. Sheets will refresh automatically as well.

If you run it again, sheet named 1 will be untouched. All other sheets will be wiped off and recreated.

Give it a try. Once successful, delete all sheets except 1. Switch your connection to SQL Server and test Sheet 1. After it works well, just press CTRL + SHIFT + T and you will have multiple sheets with the data you are looking for.