# How to have an SSRS report export to different excel sheets by each subreport?

Tags: excel, reporting-services, spreadsheet, subreport

I have a report that contains several subreports that are very similar to the main/base report. I want each subreport's data to be housed on a separate tab when the user exports the report as Excel.

I found a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462902/reporting-services-export-to-excel-with-multiple-worksheets), but it's not subreport-specific (I don't see a "PageBreak" property on Subreports, so the answer there doesn't seem to help me).

How can I cause the exported Excel file to break into separate sheets on each subreport, and with the name of each subreport on its respective sheet or the text property of the label that I place above each subreport?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the subreport inside of a rectangle control and set the PageBreak options on the rectangle.

Comment: Okay, I see a PageBreak property on the Rectangle I plopped, then dropped a subreport on/into; its Disabled subproperty is already set to False, and I set "BreakLocation" to "Start" - the report has been hourglassing for several minutes now, so I'll see what (eventually) happens...

Comment: How do you name the tabs that the subreports end up in?