# SSRS (RDL) export to Excel with web site link issue

Tags: excel, reporting-services, export-to-excel

I tried to export a report from SSRS (RDL) to Excel (. XSLX) format. The report which contain links in a column. If the report exceeds 65000 rows, its throwing alert message while opening the exported Excel file.

[image: EXCEL error]

Comment: What software are you using to create the SSRS report?

MS state that 65000 rows is the limit that an XLS file can handle and if you're using Report Builder 3, you can only export to XLS, not XLSX.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @JonTout - Yes, using VS SQL reporting service update 3 to create the SSRS Report.

Comment: Note: if exporting (. XSLX) with less than 65000 means its working fine.

Comment: You would need to source an alternate rendering tool for XLSX as that version of RS won't export to RS and you'll be stuck with the limitations.

The only "workaround" is to ding some sort of grouping and create a report that outputs to Excel with multiple tabs - as per...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462902/reporting-services-export-to-excel-with-multiple-worksheets

Comment: @JonTout - Thanks for your reply, is any other way to fix this issue without page break...

Comment: @SambathKumarS - I believe MS introduced the XLSX export in SQL 2012 and removed it again in later releases, why I don't know!

The only other "fix" is this product, which I've not used.
http://blog.softartisans.com/2011/11/01/exporting-xlsx-with-sql-server-2008-r2-reporting-services/